# Hyperplane Separation Theorem, Obtaining a Linear Functional with Norm equal to 1

Tags: functional-analysis

I am currently studying the Hyperplane separation theorem as stated on page 292 of the 4th edition of Royden's Real Analysis:

**Hyperplane Separation Theorem** Let $ X $ be a locally convex topological vector space, $ K $ a nonempty closed convex subset of $ X $, and $ x_0 $ a point in $ X $ that lies outside of $ K $.  Then $ K $ and $ x_0 $ may be separated by a closed hyperplane, that is, there is a continuous linear functional $ \psi : X \to \mathbb{R} $ for which

$$ \psi (x_0) < \inf_{x \in K} \psi (x) $$

And the following corollary:

**Corollary 25** Let $ X $ be a normed linear space, $ K $ a nonempty strongly closed convex subset of $ X $, and $ x_0 $ a point in $ X $ that lies outside of $ K $.  Then there is a functional $ \psi \in X^* $ for which

$$ \psi (x_0) < \inf_{x \in K} \psi (x) $$

For corollary 25, can we assume that $ \| \psi \| = 1 $? I have noticed that a few results using corollary 25 explicitly assume this and I cannot see why this assumption can be made.

Comment: $\phi=\psi/\|\psi\|$. That inequality can be divided by a constant positive number $\|\psi\|$ and still hold. The constant will enter the $\inf$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, just normalize $\psi$. The inequality still holds for the normalization. You know that in this case, the $\psi$ given by corollary 25 is nonzero, since otherwise you do not get  a strict inequality.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now!  I can't believe it was this obvious.  Thank you (and yixing)!!